# how to dynamically add a table row from a external php file using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

hi i have a form which will dynamically generate a table row when a user clicks on add button
i am generating a row from an external php file because the row consist of a combo box which will be populated with mysql data but when a try to generate the table row it does not append any table row i have tried checking my data in console.log  the data is being transfered but does not append is there any problem with my code ??.. can anyone help me out it would be a huge favor thanks in advance 
here is my script

```
    $(document).ready(function(){ 

        $('#addnew').click(function(){

            var ctr = $('#items').val();
            ctr++;
            $.post('purch_srch.php', {ctr : ctr}, function(data) {
                  $(data).appendTo('#detail');

                  $('#items').val(ctr);                        
            });
        });
    });
```

here is my php

```
<?php
session_start();
require("includes/dbconnect.php");
include ('includes/function.php');

$zdb = $_SESSION["zdbyear"];
mysql_select_db($zdb);

if ($_REQUEST["ctr"]){
    $ctr = $_REQUEST["ctr"];

    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" maxlength="6" name="ord_'.$ctr.'" class="form-input-oth"/></td>';
    echo "<td align='center'>";
    echo '<select data-placeholder="Party" style="width:120px;" name="item_'.$ctr.'" class="chzn-select-deselect" >';
    echo "<option value = '' ></option>";
    $get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM accmast WHERE `grpcode`='010'") or die(mysql_error());
      while($cc = mysql_fetch_array($get)){
            echo "<option value='.$cc[accode].'/>$cc[name]</option>";
      }echo"</select>";
      echo "</td>";
    echo "</select></td>";
    echo '<td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="9" maxlength="6" name="descrip_'.$ctr.'" class="form-input-name"/></td>';
    echo '<td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="9" maxlength="6" name="unit_'.$ctr.'" class="form-input-rate"/></td>';
    echo '<td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="9" maxlength="6" name="totqty_'.$ctr.'" class="qty form-input-rate"/></td>';
    echo '<td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="9" maxlength="6" name="rate_'.$ctr.'" class="rate form-input-rate"/></td>';
    echo '<td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="9" maxlength="6" name="amt_'.$ctr.'" class="cal  form-input-amt"/></td>';
    echo "</tr>";
    exit();
}
else{
    echo "ERROR";
}
```

here is my table

```
<table id="detail" border="1px" width="90%">
 </table>
<input type="button" id="addnew" class="classname" name="addnew" value="+" /> 
                          <input type="text" id="items" name="items" value="0" />
```

Comment: Do you get any error if you browse to the php file? Does it return( the php file ) the desired result?

Comment: yup it returns the desired result but now the problem is that the data is not returned in <tr></tr> form

Comment: what does it mean that the data is not returned in <tr></tr> form?

Answer (score 0):

look here: http://api.jquery.com/load/
then look here: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/load-but-append-data-instead-of-replace

Just make an example with Silex.

Controller that return source table.

```
$app->get(
'/table',
function () use ($app) {
    return '
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>13</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>21</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>23</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>31</td>
            <td>32</td>
            <td>33</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    ';
}
```

);

My destination table index-template '/':

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and jQuery here (index template /):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('table').append($('<tr>').load('/table tr:last td'));
    });
```

Result is (copy from firebug inspector):

```
<table>
    <tbody><tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
    </tr>
<tr><td>31</td><td>32</td><td>33</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution :

```
$('#detail').append(data);
```

In your code, the problem comes from $(data). If you want to generate an html tag, use `$('<tr>').html(data)`, but then you need to remove your `<tr></tr>` tag from the data.